# Why can't I update my data in lightweight charts?

Tags: reactjs, lightweight-charts

This is my initial data

```
var array = [
      {
        time: "2022-04-18",
        open: Number(`${125.05}`),
        high: Number(`${127.05}`),
        low: Number(`${123.05}`),
        close: Number(`${126.05}`),
      },
    ];
```

When I try to update the charts with the same data format like this:

```
updated.unshift({
            time: `${key}`,
            open: Number(`${val[["1. open"]]}`),
            high: Number(`${val[["2. high"]]}`),
            low: Number(`${val[["4. close"]]}`),
            close: Number(`${val[["4. close"]]}`),
          });
```

it gives me an error
lightweight-charts.esm.production.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'year')

Answer (score 1):

After you've set your data for the series using [`setData`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ISeriesApi#setdata), you can use [`update`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ISeriesApi#update) to add new data to the series. Please note that this method can only take a single data point at a time and the time must either match the last data point of the series or be a later date.

If you are using `unshift` then you are adding data to the start of the array. If you are modifying the array yourself then you need to use the `setData` method again with the array as the parameter. This will replace all the data for that series with the new data. This isn't as performant as the `updateData` method but if you are wanting to add to the start of the array then this is the approach you will need to use.

```js
array = [
      {
        time: "2022-04-18",
        open: 125.05,
        high: 127.05,
        low: 123.05,
        close: 126.05,
      },
      // ... more data
    ];
series.setData(array);

// ...

// adding new data point to end of data
series.update({
  time: "2022-04-19",
  open: 123.4,
  close: 123.4,
  high: 123.4,
  low: 123.4,
});

// If you need to add to the start then you will need to use setData
array.unshift({
  time: "2022-04-19",
  open: 123.4,
  close: 123.4,
  high: 123.4,
  low: 123.4,
});
series.setData(array); // Not recommended in most use cases.
```