# How to use datetime values in react lightweight-charts

Tags: reactjs, datetime, tradingview-api

I am trying to build an OHLC chart using real-time data in react using `lightweight-charts` node package. I am using

```
createChart
addCandlestickSeries
and setting candlestickSeries.setData()
```

However, I couldn't find any documentation on how to pass timestamp or datetime to the time field.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73681859/why-cant-i-update-my-data-in-lightweight-charts might help